# Special Interest immigration

Tags: usa, immigration

On occasion I've found that there are programs set up for bringing people of particular ethnicity or technical skills into the US.

Is there a way to find what programs like this are currently in effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is called "INA" - Immigration and Nationality Act. You can find it in any legal library (including virtual ones). It is also [available freely](http://www.uscis.gov/iframe/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/act.html) on the USCIS website.

Specifically you probably want to read Chapters 1 and 2 of Title II of the act.

In the US, all the immigration and admission classes and categories are coded in statute, so you just need to read it.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the categories of immigrants.  I was looking for special programs that are designed to make process basically a formality rather then a necessity.  Like refugee programs for Soviet Jews, and Green Cards for scientists and engineers involved in Soviet nuclear weapons programs.

Comment: @Karlson you'd be surprised, but these were codified. It now reads as "asylum" category.

Comment: Not sure I follow...

Comment: I think he's saying all those other ones come under the same heading of the 'asylum' category now.

Comment: @MarkMayo The question is not what category they fall under but what are those groups.

Comment: There are no groups. Never have been. People who are prosecuted at home for being themselves can get asylum in the US, and it applies to the Soviet Jews just as it does to the Iranian gays. There's no "program". There used to be a program for nurses (codified in the INA as a special category), but that was canceled more than a decade ago. There are special programs for Singapore, Chile, Australia, Canada, Mexico - these are based on treaties and are codified. What you're looking for - doesn't exist.